# Swagger UI - How to Show a List of Models by themselves

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, api-design, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

In the Swagger Editor example, http://editor.swagger.io/#/, there is a "Models" section later on in the rendered document after the endpoints are shown.  Is this only a feature of this editor to see how things are looking at you define them, or is this also possible to display all models in Swagger UI?

(It would be really great if they could be also displayed outside of the endpoint information, especially for models that are defined but not used yet...so collaborators can see what's coming.)

Comment: ANy solution or idea so far? How did you display model? I have inheritance and thus I would like to show all models that extend certain model.

Comment: I found that there is already issue for that: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1052 this is now part of 3.0.